# build PhoneGap Application with ChildBrowser Plugin

Tags: xml, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to build an application with a child browser plugin. when I build the app from eclipse it works fine but when i use only the html ,css ,and javascript at phonegap build it isn't working as i thought it is because the .java used at eclipse dosn't exist at the www file. any one can help me how to build my application and use child browser
the config.xml used is as the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin=".*"/>
<content src="index.html" />
<log level="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
<plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
<plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
<plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
<plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
<plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
<plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
<plugin name="parse" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.parse"/>
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
<plugin name="SmsPlugin" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.SmsPlugin"/>
<plugin name="WaitingDialog" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.WaitingDialog"/>
<plugin name="DialogPlugin" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.DialogPlugin"/>
<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.ChildBrowser"/>
<plugin name="GoogleAnalyticsTracker" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.GoogleAnalyticsTracker"/> 
<plugin name="AddDoctorServicePlugin" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.AddDoctorServicePlugin"/>
<plugin name="ContactView" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.ContactView"/>
<plugin name="DatePickerPlugin" value="com.example.drbridgepatients.DatePickerPlugin"/>

</plugins>
</cordova>
```

any one can help me is building phonegap app with child browser and how to write my config.xml

when i try to write

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function (loc) { self.onLocationChange(loc); };
```

also i changed the config file to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    versionCode="10" 
    version   = "1.0.0">

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>PhoneGap Example</name>

<description>
    An example for phonegap build docs. 
</description>

<author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    Hardeep Shoker 
</author>
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="img/Android_36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />


    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.5.0" />
<gap:plugin name="ChildBrowser"/>

</widget>
```